# ADBannerView not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, iad

I'm trying to put iAd Banner into my game! I've been starring at the game for quite a while to wait for the normal Apple iAd advertisement to come up but it hasn't. It isn't appearing on my screen at all!

Am I doing something wrong?

Or will it appear eventually?

```
import iAd


var iAdBanner = ADBannerView()

var bannerVisible = false

class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate{


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)



        iAdBanner.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.width, 50)
        iAdBanner.delegate = self
        bannerVisible = false
    }
}

// Show banner, if Ad is successfully loaded.
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    if(bannerVisible == false) {

        // Add banner Ad to the view
        if(iAdBanner.superview == nil) {
            self.view.addSubview(iAdBanner)
        }

        // Move banner into visible screen frame:
        UIView.beginAnimations("iAdBannerShow", context: nil)
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height)
        UIView.commitAnimations()

        bannerVisible = true
    }

}

// Hide banner, if Ad is not loaded.
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    if(bannerVisible == true) {
        // Move banner below screen frame:
        UIView.beginAnimations("iAdBannerHide", context: nil)
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height)
        UIView.commitAnimations()
        bannerVisible = false
    }

}
```

Comment: Too much code.. please edit your question and show only the code that is relevant to 'adding' a ad banner...

Comment: @lukya ok, I deleted a lot of the code and just left the adding the ad banner!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not added the banner view to your view. You have called `self.view.addSubview(iAdBanner)` in `bannerViewDidLoadAd` which will not get called before adding the banner view. You need to add the banner view beforehand (e.g. in `viewDidLoad`).

Also, you cant change the banner view frame to any size you want .

Read through the [Banner View Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/BannerAdvertisements/BannerAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH3-SW8) in iAD Programming Guide (actually read the entire guide). It has code snippets (in ObjC not Swift though).

It clearly says :

> iAd supports different banner sizes for portrait and landscape apps.
>   The exact size of advertisements depends on the device the banner is
>   being shown on. On an iPhone, a portrait advertisement is 320 x 50
>   points and 480 x 32 points for a landscape advertisement. On an iPad,
>   a portrait advertisement is 768 x 66 points and 1024 x 66 points for a
>   landscape advertisement. In the future, additional sizes may be
>   exposed by iAd.

And in the next paragraph:

> To ensure that advertisements are displayed properly, a banner view
>   must always be sized to match one of the built-in advertising sizes.
>   The ADBannerView class enforces this by preventing you from changing
>   the frame directly. Instead, you change a banner view’s frame by
>   setting the currentContentSizeIdentifier property. Changing the value
>   stored in this property resizes the banner view’s frame to the match
>   the size for the provided identifier.

Comment: Do you mean I need to add self.view.addSubview(iAdBanner) to the viewDidLoad? Sorry, I'm quite new to this iAd and adding it to swift! Also how would I go about making it so the banner view frame size to the normal size it is suppose to be at?

Comment: Yes you can add it in viewDidLoad and you do not need to set it's frame.

Comment: Please read through the guide in the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/BannerAdvertisements/BannerAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH3-SW8) You will have a much better idea.

Comment: I have added the self.view.addSubview(iAdBanner) to my viewDidLoad, and I have also deleted all of the banner  frame codes which there was 3 `iAdBanner.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.width, 50)` `banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height)` `banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height)` and now there is a white box on the top of the screen when I run the game and no ads appear yet! Also, I have read the link you provided, but I have no clue on how to convert the objC to swift as I'm really new to this.

Comment: Since you are writing this in swift, you at least know Swift. Forget the code snippets if you dont want to look at ObjC code but **READ** the entire guide to understand how to work with iAds. You can then write the code yourself in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

maybe check your storyboard--> your viewcontroller which contains iAd --> view attributes inspector tab --> focus on Extend Edges, & uncheck this attribute. Hope this help. Tks for reading this answer.